# Compare Two Dates and Display The Earlier One

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

Cells B2 and B3 each have a date entered in them. I want to compare the two dates and display the earlier date in cell C2.  Or, stated another way:

if B2 < B3, display B2 in cell C2
if B3 < B2, display B3 in cell C2

I do something like this with Acrobat's JavaScript but am lost with Google Sheets.

```
var date1 = this.getField("txt_date.0").value;
var date2 = this.getField("txt_date.1").value;

if(date1 < date2)
event.value = date1;
if(date2 < date1)
event.value = date2;
```

Answer (score 2):

I got some assistance with this. Either of the following will work. Posting in case it helps someone else.

```
=IF(B2<B3,B2,B3)
```

or

```
=MIN(B2:B3)
```

Comment: _Posting in case it helps someone else._ Always a good idea - paying it forward.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't post comments because I haven't reached 50 reputation points.
However, I cannot fail to recommend only the first formula and to reject the second, at least for how it was written ... the second can give an incorrect result if the two cells (B2 and B3) are emptied and C2 has been formatted as date

Comment: Use `=iferror( 1 / min(B2:B3) ^ -1 )`.

Comment: yes, that solve the above problem